# How to append url using javascript in particular pattern

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to append variable data in js in below code in url

```
$(document).on('change','.sort_rang',function(){
   var url = "ajax_search.php";
   //console.log($("#search_form").serialize());
   var data = $("#search_form").serialize();
   //data += "&pn="+ <?php echo $_GET['pn']; ?>;
   //console.log(data);
   $.ajax({ 
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: function(response)
     {                  
        $('.ajax_result').html(response);
     }               
   });

  return false;
});
```

How to append the url in below format,

`?pg=2&company=motorola,lenovo&pricerange=2`
I want to append url in ajax_search.php

after `var_dump($_REQUEST)`. I'm getting this

```
array(4) { ["company"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Lenovo" } 
["category"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "mobile" } ["pricerange"]=> 
string(1) "1" ["pricesort"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

From this i want to append on above format

Comment: Why would you want to do that when you have post and data. Just do data+="&pg=2&company=motorola,lenovo&pricerange=2"

Comment: You have the URL there and you don't know how to copypaste that to the URL? Or concatenate strings?

Comment: make a get request although `.serialize()` is serializing the string for you in the same manner but with `?` at the start.

Comment: I have url to be like that becaue my pagination and sorting is not working

Comment: Do you want to send the variables as an URL along with the serialized data ?

Comment: i want to append that url bcuz i can use that for $_GET request

Comment: Are `pg`, `company` and `pricerange` parameters fields of your form (`$("#search_form")`)?

Comment: Then you just need to change the `type` parameter of your ajax request, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service (**ajax_search.php**) requires the GET method then you can simply change the `type` parameter of your `$.ajax` request from `type: "POST"` to `type: "GET"` then jQuery does the job, you don't need to append the string to the URL by hand.

```
$(document).on('change','.sort_rang',function(){
    var url = "ajax_search.php";
    //console.log($("#search_form").serialize());
    var data = $("#search_form").serialize();
    //data += "&pn="+ <?php echo $_GET['pn']; ?>;
    //console.log(data);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", // <-- Note the change here from POST to GET
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {                  
            $('.ajax_result').html(response);
        }               
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you have some kind of error? With `var_dump($_GET)` in your PHP file do you see anything?